# How to hide category name on category page only for second level category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, name, sub-categories, hide

I want to hide the category name on the category page only for the sub category of only one parent category.
The category names will be displayed for all other categories and sub categories.
For e.g I have Cat A-> Cat B -> Cat C
And Cat D-> Cat E-> Cat F

I want to hide all the category names on category page of level Cat B.
For rest, it will be displayed.

Comment: Hi so you need to hide second-level category right

Comment: Yes, i do not want to display names for second level categroy on category page. That too only for one parent category. For other second level category it will be displayed

Comment: Can you share your url please

Comment: https://wazoodle01.wsisites.net/index.php/fabrics/zorb.html

Comment: i wanna hide for all the categories only under fabrics

Comment: so you want to remove all list category hide https://wazoodle01.wsisites.net/index.php/fabrics.html on this page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105684/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-nafisa).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have over ride following files.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

In your theme like below

```
app/design/frontend/mytheme/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

Comment: Then what to do in that?